# How to export SQL Server database into Microsoft Access (2007)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007, sql-server-2005-express

How can I export SQL Server into Microsoft Access 2007? At present I can view tables but I can't view stored procedures and how to save exported database from SQL Server into MS Access. So that I can call the path in connection string.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Tasks > Export Data` context menu choice in SQL Server's Object Explorer?

Comment: You can link the tables from within Access, and create Pass Through Queries in Access to get at the Stored Procedures. Once you have both in Access, you can create APPEND queries that pull from those sources into Access tables. This is only one approach. You can also Import from SQL via ODBC.

Comment: Is this a one time export (migration)? Or is this a recurring export (ETL, extract-transform-load)?